# AngularFire: data is still accessible after logout

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm struggling with user authentication and authorization with AngularFire.

The issue is that once an authorized user is logged in and the data from Firebase is displayed, if I log out then the data is still displayed. I can detach the data from the scope (`delete $scope.data`) which makes it not display, but then if I log in again as an *unauthorized* user, the reference is reattached and the data is still there.

I guess the data is retained client-side somewhere. But how can I destroy it? I have tried  replacing the Firebase reference by a new one each time I log out, in vain.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-hide="loggedIn">Not logged In</div>
  <button ng-hide="loggedIn" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>

  <div>The data: {{data}}</div>
  <button ng-show="loggedIn" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

angular.module('app', ['firebase'])

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin) {
  var ref = new Firebase(<ref>);
  var ngref = $firebase(ref);
  var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
  $scope.loggedIn = !!auth.user;
  $scope.login = function () {
    auth.$login('google').then(
      function (user) {
        $scope.data = ngref.name;
        $scope.loggedIn = true;
      }, 
      function (error) {
        throw error;
      });
  };
  $scope.logout = function () {
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
    auth.$logout();
  };
})

</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

It seems that this behavior has nothing to do with AngularFire. The code below uses the vanilla Firebase API and the result is the same.

```
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function (error, user) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  } else if (user) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.loggedIn = true;
      $scope.data = ref;
    });
  } else {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      delete $scope.data;
      $scope.loggedIn = false;
    });
  }
});

$scope.loggedIn = false;
$scope.login = function () {
  auth.login('google');
};
$scope.logout = function () {
  auth.logout();
};
```

Comment: Your `data` object is just the Firebase instance (not the data in Firebase). It's not going to disappear because you've logged out. loggedIn var is updating fine when I try your example above. I don't understand what you are expecting to go away. Naturally, anything you assign to $scope will remain on $scope--it's simply a JavaScript variable in memory; Firebase doesn't purge your browser memory somehow when it logs out. Can you clarify, perhaps with a fiddle/example, the precise issues here?

Comment: I understand that the Firebase *reference* remains in memory, however I expected it to purge the data it contains on logout. Since it does not, I'm asking how I can make sure logging out makes the data unaccessible. I have edited the question and code to show that the issue persists even if the reference is detached from the scope on logout, with `delete $scope.data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit late (almost a year), however this can be fixed by removing the localStorage entry for "firebase:session::".

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("firebase:session::<host-name>");
```

Comment: Looks like it works! The item's name was different though. Using Firebase 1.0.18 I had to remove the `firebaseSession` item in local storage.